# Spring MVC 4 response body serialization works with JSON but not with XML

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am working on setting up REST API with Spring 4. The HTTP Message converters are present by default for JSON & XML. I try to setup two end-points, one for returning JSON & another for XML. The JSON object seems to be returned as expected but when i try to hit xml, i end up with 406 exception,

> The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.

I have included the Maven dependencies for both JSON & XML. Below is the Snippet of pom.xml,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId> 
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency> 

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId> 
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId> 
    <version>${jaxb-api.version}</version> 
</dependency>
```

Below is the controller code,

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/employee")
public class HelloController {

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET , produces="application/json",value="/hello.json")
public List<Employee> getEmployeeJson(){

    Employee emp = new Employee();
    emp.setId(1);
    emp.setName("x");

    Employee emp1 = new Employee();
    emp1.setId(2);
    emp1.setName("y");

    List<Employee> res = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    res.add(emp);
    res.add(emp1);

    return res;
}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET , produces="application/xml",value="/hello.xml")
public List<Employee> getEmployeeXml(){

    Employee emp = new Employee();
    emp.setId(1);
    emp.setName("x");

    Employee emp1 = new Employee();
    emp1.setId(2);
    emp1.setName("y");

    List<Employee> res = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    res.add(emp);
    res.add(emp1);

    return res;
}

}
```

Do share your thoughts on what am missing here

Comment: Also why 2 methods? When using content negotiation you don't need that... A single mapping for `/hello` is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-write-an-xml-rest-service) you should add `jackson-dataformat-xml` dependency to enable response body XML serialization. In case you are using Maven just add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. But the domain class is already annotated with `@XmlRootElement`. Not sure if something else is missed out

Comment: @AshwinSridhar I've tried it on my Spring Boot app and it worked there. So it might be some dependency/configuration difference. Take a look at [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html). It states that if you add `jackson-dataformat-xml` dependency it should also work, otherwise it should fallback to JAXB, which obviously didn't happen ... strange.

Comment: Thank you very much adding the @jackson-dataformat-xml did the trick.